# Android - When should I escape unicode in Strings.xml resource file?

Tags: android, unicode, android-resources, unicode-escapes, android-resource-file

According to documentation unicode characters should be used with \u prefix in strings.xml file. For example use `\u00a9`  instead of `©`.

```
<string name="copyright_text">Copyrighted ©</string>
```

But if I write © directly it seems to work fine even in API 21.  Is there any scenario where it is really needed to scape other than other more impactfull characters such ash &, < >, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a definitive authority to point to, but in my own personal experience the only reason I have found to use the `\u` notation is when the character is visually ambiguous. For example, I use `\u2013` instead of an actual en-dash character `"–"` because the glyph is so visually similar to the standard hyphen `"-"`. Another common scenario is using `\u00a0` instead of an actual non-breaking space character.

As far as I am aware, there is no technical reason to not use unicode characters in your strings file, as long as the file itself is using a character encoding that supports them.

Note that Android Studio's lint feature will actually prompt you to use these special characters in certain scenarios:

[image]

Applying the suggested fix leaves you with an ellipsis character `"…"`, not the encoding for one.